# Chrome Extension Content Script to send all <h1>

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm new to building chrome extensions and I would like to have my content script access all of the h1 tags on the page and send it to my background page so I can manipulate them.

I've been reading through a lot of answers and still can't seem to get my code to run properly.

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
 { "code": "test" },
  function(results){
    console.log(results);
 });
```

content.js

```
var test = function(){
  var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

}
```

What I believe my background.js is doing is calling the test function in my content.js file, and then whatever gets passed back will be console.log as the results. I'm not sure if I should be using the chrome.extension.sendMessage in my content script and a Listener in my background file.

My goal is just for the background.js file to console.log the results to ensure I am getting the correct h1 tags back, and from there I will continue to manipulate the results.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: DOM elements cannot be JSON-serialized. You should manipulate the tags in the content script, then return the result as a string, number, array, boolean or plain object.

Comment: @RobW how can I return the result to the background.js file? The result seems to just return null when I console.log them.

Comment: You're not calling the function. Add () after test.